# Unable to get custom logs in Docker container while running war in inside tomcat image

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

I am using `logback.xml` file to log in SpringBoot application..When I deploy the war file inside my local machine in tomcat then I can see the log file named `test_app1.log` being generated inside `tomcat\logs\test_app1.log` file...But when I run it in docker container, I can see the logs in terminal but the `test_app1.log` is not generated inside  `/usr/local/tomcat/logs` directory of docker container..Can someone help me in resolving it?

My dockerfile content is below:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM tomcat:9-jdk17-temurin-focal

COPY target/test-app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

My docker command is as below;

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 test:v1
```

pom.xml file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Branch>${branch}</Branch>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and logback.xml file below:

```
<configuration>
    <property name="APPLICATION_NAME" value="test-app" />
    <property name="LOG_ROOT" value="../logs" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE_NAME" value="${APPLICATION_NAME}.server.log" />

    <appender name="STDOUT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date [%thread] [%-5level] %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_ROOT}/${LOG_FILE_NAME}</file>
        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ROOT}/${LOG_FILE_NAME}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>18</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.test.APP" level="INFO"
        additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This will depend on how you start the container command and parameters and how the tomcat image used is configured.

Comment: Show your dockerfile and  docker run command.

Comment: @life888888 added in edits my dockerfile and docker run command..pls check it

Comment: pom.xml ? logback*.xml ?

Comment: logback.xml will be inside war file: war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml and pom.xml will be inside war/META-INF/maven/com.test/pom.xml ..they are packaged inside war when I generate a war file

Comment: @life888888 pls see above comment..I followed the link below to do it https://www.baeldung.com/docker-deploy-java-war

Comment: Sorry, I mean show pom.xml and logback file content.

Comment: @life888888 edited to include contents

Comment: @life888888 I also tried the link but could not resolve the issue..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528286/logging-to-file-using-docker-and-logback...my test-app.server.log is not generated inside /usr/local/tomcat/logs directory inside container..but it is generated when i run it inside tomcat server in my local file system

Comment: @life888888 just curious, why ../logs does not work but ${catalina.base}/logs works despite both refers the same and why it is working in local file system but not in container?

Comment: run `docker ps`, find container id. if container id is `3ff45f65a4bd`, run `docker exec -it 3ff45f65a4bd bash`, then `ls`, find `logs` dir in which directory ? `tomcat` or `bin` or others ?

Comment: I test your config , in container, it will in `/usr/local/logs/test_app1.log`, ( `docker exec -it 6914f6fdd859 bash`, `cd ../` , `ls` ) , you can find `../`, like logback.xml `"../logs"`

Comment: @life888888 no no..my doubt is why " ../" does not go to the immediate parent directory in docker but in local file system it goes to immediate parent directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**logback.xml**

```
<property name="LOG_ROOT" value="${catalina.base}/logs" />
```

## My Simplest logback.xml

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds" debug="false">
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/logs/test_app1.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <!-- set immediateFlush to false for much higher logging throughput -->
    <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```